# Reloading child component route reloads the parent parent component

Tags: angular

I am having a parent route and under this I have my child routes as follows.

```
const routes : Routes = [
            {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, 
            children: [
            { path: 'airetail', component: AiretailplatformComponent},
            { path: 'cpr', component: CprComponent },
            { path: 'snap', component: SnapComponent},
            { path: 'others', component: OthersComponent },
            { path: 'docs', component: DocumentationComponent },
            {path: 'dynamic', component: AiRetailDynamicComponent}
            ],
            {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: full}
        }
     ]
```

Whenever I am in any of the child routes and try to reload any of the child route components the parent route also gets called. Is there a way I can restrict calling my parent route, here HomeComponent whenever I reload the child route pages?

Answer (score -1):

use the relative route.

in your .component.ts

```
constructor(
private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
private router: Router)  {

   routeToPath() {
      this.router.navigate(['<your-path>'], { relativeTo: activateRoute 
      })
   }
}
```

This will only load the child route.

Comment: I am using routerLink in my solution to navigate to child route which is working fine. But i face issue only while clicking the browser refresh button and the home component template is getting reloaded along with my child component.

Comment: what do you expect then?